# wordpress website is being redirected to some other website

Tags: wordpress, security

I set up my blog with wordpress cms few days ago and it was working fine, url is [blog](http://blog.edgrab.com),I also noticed that it only happens only on few network connection.for e.g.:  it works fine on my mobile data pack and wifi connection but in my office it got redirected to some other web page.

How and why it is happenings have already checked `.htaccess`and `dns`
and found nothing suspicious.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working correctly. Check with your office's network administrator.

Additionally, scan your files for any spam injection.

Comment: actually we are a startup and using normal internet connections we don't have any network administrators and already scanned my files for spam injection but did n't found any malware